# lein 2.5.2 uberjar NoClassDefFoundError after adding a new source-path, but success without it

Tags: clojure, leiningen, uberjar

I am struggling in making a jar file, it just won't work if I add source-paths. I ran

```
lein with-profiles prod uberjar
```

Here is my project.clj I have shortened it a bit, mostly it contains luminus template.

```
(defproject codapay "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

 :description "FIXME: write description"
 :url "http://example.com/FIXME"

 :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                [selmer "0.9.0"]
                [org.immutant/web "2.0.2"]
                [clj-http "2.0.0"]
                [cheshire "5.5.0"]
                ........
                [environ "1.0.0"]
                [com.stuartsierra/component "0.2.3"]]

  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :uberjar-name "codapay.jar"
  :jvm-opts ["-server"]
  :target-path "target/%s/"
  :plugins [[lein-environ "1.0.0"]]
  :profiles
  {:prod {;;:omit-source true
         :env {:production true}
         :aot :all
         :source-paths ["dev"]
         :uberjar-name "coda.jar"
         :main codapay.core}})
```

and this is my main

```
(ns codapay.core
  (:require [codapay.handler :refer [app init destroy]]
            [immutant.web :as immutant]
            [clojure.tools.nrepl.server :as nrepl]
            [taoensso.timbre :as timbre]
            [environ.core :refer [env]]
            [codapay.entry :refer [start-app]])
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main [& args]
  (start-app args))
```

I execute the jar files with

```
java -jar coda.jar
```

It dies with this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at clojure.lang.Namespace.<init>(Namespace.java:34)
        at clojure.lang.Namespace.findOrCreate(Namespace.java:176)
        at clojure.lang.Var.internPrivate(Var.java:151)
        at codapay.core.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clout/core/CompiledRoute, compiling:(user.clj:1:1)
```

Said by the error that it can't found clout/core/CompiledRoute, but when I extract the jar file, it was there.
There is also weird thing in compilation, that the extra source-paths compiled twice when I ran uberjar.

But when I erase the source-paths on profiles prod, it works normally.

I tried to run it with

```
lein with-profiles prod run
```

It received the same error, but will run succesfully if either the aot or source-paths is deleted

In case you're curious how the real project looked like, here is the link

> https://github.com/calvinirwan/codapay/tree/uberjar

Comment: You don't have a source-path on your `project.clj` except in the profile ? That sounds odd.

Comment: Try `with-profiles +prod` so it adds prod to the default profiles

Comment: To be more precise, that's so the prod profile is merged over the defaults in https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/leiningen-core/src/leiningen/core/project.clj#L191 and probably other profiles

Comment: I think the project defaults will include source-paths "src". But should I add the "src" path in the project ?

Comment: I already tried `with-profiles +prod run` still caught in the same error, the thing that bug me is, when I extract the jar file, the `clout/core/CompiledRoute` is exist normally